# Don't expose functions from imported packages in own package in R

Tags: r, dplyr, package

I know this is a real beginners question, and I'd be happy to any pointer to any help. But I found it quite complicated to find some more or less easy to read resource.

So the question is that I want to create a package in R. Let's say I want to use many functions from the `dplyr`-package. So I do a `@import dplyr` at the top of my `utils.R` where I have many small functions that do some data cleaning etc..

Now when I load all my own functions with `devtools::load_all()` and start typing the name of my package and `::` I get suggestions for all the functions from the dplyr-package as well.

What essential aspect am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either import only specific functions from `dplyr` using the line

```
@importFrom dplyr usefulFunction
```

which reduces the number of functions that you'll have problems with, or you can remove the `import` totally, and then refer to functions including the package name, for example `dplyr::usefulFunction()` whenever you use a function from `dplyr`.

Comment: thanks:)! I thought there might be another way of importing all functions from dplyr but not exposing them and also not having to type the `::` each time I use a dplyr function.